# Multiple ViewModels in Knockout observables

Tags: knockout.js

I got a problem with a multiple ViewModel in Knockout.js.
The binding works, but when the message box appears which should display the text of the user observable it always writes "undefined".

Anyone knows hat my problem is?

```
<!-- ko template: { 'if': loginVM, data: loginVM } -->
    <h3>This is the login</h3>

    User <input type="value: user" type="text"><br/>
    Password <input type="value: password" type="text"><br/>
    <button data-bind="click: showDetails">Show Details</button>
<!-- /ko -->

<!-- ko template: { 'if': detailsVM, data: detailsVM } -->
    <h1>These are the details</h1>
    <button data-bind="click: showLogin">Show Login</button>
<!-- /ko -->

    var masterViewModel = {
        loginVM: ko.observable(),
        detailsVM: ko.observable()
    };

    var LoginVM = function () {
        this.user=ko.observable();
        this.password= ko.observable();
        this.showDetails = function () {
            alert(this.user());
            if(this.user() == "Gregor")
            {
                 masterViewModel.loginVM(null);
                 masterViewModel.detailsVM(new DetailsVM());
            }

        };
    };

    var DetailsVM = function () {
        this.showLogin = function () {
            masterViewModel.loginVM(new LoginVM());
            masterViewModel.detailsVM(null);
        };
    };

    masterViewModel.loginVM(new LoginVM()); 

    ko.applyBindings(masterViewModel);​
```

Here also is a js.fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4A87x/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in the bindings. Should be:

```
User <input data-bind="value: user" type="text"><br/>
Password <input data-bind="value: password" type="text"><br/>
```

Working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/4A87x/3/

Comment: Also with is a better binding here since you use inline templates anyway http://jsfiddle.net/4A87x/6/

Comment: I'm now facing another little problem!

if I click the showStart button in my DetailsVM i have to click twice to hide the DetialsVM!

http://jsfiddle.net/4A87x/9/

Comment: @Greg: I refactored your code. To me this way seems better. And it works. Hope it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/4A87x/13/

Comment: thank you!

I think this might seem strange to you, but this fiddles are not working correctly if i use them in ASP.NET MVC4 
the "<!-- ko template: { 'if': detailsVM, data: detailsVM } -->" semms to be a comment only!
What to do to make this work?

Comment: @Greg I'm not sure, I've never used that technology, but instead of comments you can try to use dummy divs: <div data-bind="if..."><div data-bind="with..."> content </div></div>. Unfortunately, you cannot put if and with on the same element.

Comment: @Stefan
i tried it with forms but that didn't seem to work!
but thank you for your answer!
I'm gonna ask a new question

Comment: Now i was able to reproduce the mistake in js fiddle! 

Maybe you could tell me now what's wrong!

Comment: @Stefan:

Could you please answer if you've read the comment before? 
Otherwise i have to open a new question!

Comment: @Greg sorry for late response. Please do ask a new question, I'll be away from my computer for a while and I'm sure someone will help you.